# How to send SMS in Qt for Android?

Tags: android, qt, sms, qt5

What is the official API in Qt5.2 (which started supporting Android and iOS officially) for sending text messages? or generally the Messaging API.

Comment: I hope for this simple task, I don't have to go through JNI!

Comment: AFAIK you will have to fallback to the NDK provided classes, since there is no direct access to the phone core features. The accessibility is still in development here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Qt mostly work for GUI only stuff on Android. To be able to do what you want you have to call Java code from C++. I suggest you start of by extending QtActivity (and call super on the functions already implemented like onCreate() etc.). Then you would have to code using the Android [SMS Manager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

More information and an example on how to call Java code from C++/Qt can be found [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/12/12/implementing-in-app-purchase-on-android/).

This should get you started if you decide to proceed.

Comment: Thanks. I was just exploring the technology, and deciding whether to port my Symbian Qt app to Android in this way, or completely rewrite it. So it seems Qt for Android is not there yet to be a real alternative and I have to stick to native Android.